# Wolfram Mathematica: DensityHistogram or 2D Histogram of a dataset with date-time column

Tags: datetime, dataset, histogram, wolfram-mathematica, heatmap

I have a Wolfram-Mathematica dataset with 2 columns named A and B and more than 10^9 rows.

- The elements of column A are date-time. (I want to bin this column with steps of 1 Hour or 1 Day.)
- The column B includes integer values.

The data are clean, with no gaps, unevenness in the type of data, no missing data, etc.

I highlight:

1. the huge number of rows;
2. the column A has date-time values;
3. I need to select the bin width of the date-time A column (for example 1 hour or 1 Day).

I have 2 questions.

**Question 1**

I need to create a density histogram (or heatmap, or 2D histogram) of the counts/occurrences z for each fixed couple of values {x, y} from A and B.

The z counts/occurences of the density histogram should be represented with color scale (such as an heatmap):

- x axis = bins of column A (date-time);
- y axis = bins of column B;
- z axis = counts, that is the occurrences in each cell {x,y}.

I know that the DateHistogram function works fine with a single column of date-time values.
But unfortunately I cannot manage to use DateHistogram for a density histogram providing in input 2 columns (the A column with date-time values and the B column with integer values).

I tried to avoid the problem by transforming the the date-time values of the column A in integer number by using the AbsoluteTime function. But Mathematica takes a huge time running due to the large number of rows of the dataset.

**Question 2**

After plotting the density histogram, I need to extract the list of values that generates the density histogram itself, I mean the list of {x,y,z} values.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please edit your post to include a made-up data set with 12 or 20 rows that should produce one 3x3 histogram with one specified time bin width and a 2x2 histogram with a different specified time bin width and a description of what the two histograms should look like. Make that data set so it can be scraped off the screen and pasted into a notebook. With that someone can test their ideas to tell if they work. Thanks